# mininet with POX: get event when flow_mod is used

Tags: python, pox, mininet

I am not sure I understand `mininet` and `POX` well so my question might be stupid,
However, I want to know when packets are forwarded by `flow_mod` rule.

I don't want to send all the packets to the controller because they might be big so I use `flow_mods`, but I do want to know that a packet was sent on the specific link and its size (I don't need the data itself, only this metadata)
it can be metadata for several packets together, like a summery each 10 seconds for example.

Is there a way to do it or I have to send the packets to the controller and gather the statistics myself ?

Thanks.

Comment: The flow modification message is sent from controller to switch right. Are you talking for the reply?

Answer (score 0):

You can get write a python script and run it with pox for example, you write a script  **statistics.py**, you can run it with pox using the command `./pox.py forwarding.l2_learning statistics` assuming that statistics.py is placed in the same folder.

In the script, you can ping the switches with a Flow level statistics request every 10 seconds. You can find a tutorial on achieving the desired result [here](https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki#POXWiki-ofp_stats_request-Requestingstatisticsfromswitches).

By default though, only the first packet of a flow invokes a flow_mod message. You can print the details of the packet by altering your `forwarding.l2_learning`.